# How to use Heroku Review Apps with Twilio?

Tags: heroku, twilio

When a new Pull Request is created for our app, a new Heroku instance is spun up, with a new, unique URL each time.

However, the app needs to handle incoming text messages, which requires that we specify a callback URL in the Twilio dashboard.

Is there a way to solve this catch 22?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have not worked with Heroku Review apps myself, so I'm not sure, but here is an idea to follow up on.

The Heroku Review app allows you to specify a [post-deploy script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-postdeploy-script) that runs once the app is deployed. I don't know if you can get the URL for the new application within that post-deploy script or the environment, but if you can, you can then make a call to the Twilio API to either [create a new phone number and set it's `SmsUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers#list-post) or [update an existing phone number's `SmsUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post) to the new application's URL.